# Find the minimal value of a function

Tags: functions

Say we have function:

$ f(r) = \frac{b}{r} (n + 2^r), r > 0 $

where $b$ and $n$ are some constants large than $0$.

How can we determine the minimal value of this function?

---

Compute the derivative:

$f'(r) =  \frac{-b}{r^2} (n + 2^r) + \frac{b}{r}(2^r \ln 2)$

How can I solve the equation $f'(r) = 0$?

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_function

Comment: I think you could use the special function: product log
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProductLog.html

Comment: Hi, any feedback to the answers given would be nice. Thx...

Answer (score 1):

Since draks ... gave you the answer for the solution of $f'(r)=0$, for $$r_0=\frac{W\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)+1}{\log (2)}$$ you could find, after some simplifications using Lambert function properties, that $$f(r_0)=\frac{b n \log (2)}{W\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)}=\frac{b n \log (2)}{r_0 \log (2)-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $f'(r) =  \frac{-b}{r^2} (n + 2^r) + \frac{b}{r}(2^r \ln 2)=0$. You get:
$$
\frac{1}{r} (n + 2^r) = (2^r \ln 2)\\
n= r2^r\ln2-2^r=2^r(r\ln2 -1)
$$
Substitute $x=r\ln2-1$, then
$$
n=2^{(x+1)/\ln2}x=2^{x/\ln2}2^{1/\ln2}x=e^xex\\
n/e=xe^x
$$
This can be solved using [Lambert's W function: $Y=Xe^X \to X=W(Y)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications). After resubstitution you get
[$$r=\frac{W(n/e)+1}{\ln2}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ebjd2cu7d3v)

Comment: Yet you have to check if for this n, it doesn't lead to divide by 0

Comment: @aflous true, thanks, so [$n=-1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e2jfahkc34o) should be excluded...